# Python: Counting Points from 2 1D Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, counting

I have a data set of 2 1D arrays. My goal is to count the points in each section of a grid (with a size of my choosing).

```
plt.figure(figsize=(8,7))
np.random.seed(5)
x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.random(100)

plt.plot(x,y,'bo')
plt.grid(True)
```

My Plot

[image]

I would like to be able to split each section into is own unique set of 2 1D or 1 2D arrays.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) you were *supposed* to finish before posting, especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You got it wrong, looking for suggestions on useful routines or ways to work with arrays that will be helpful for me.

Comment: I'd ask another question more like how you want mr prune but the website wont let me

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

def split(arr, cond):
  return [arr[cond], arr[~cond]]

a = np.array([1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8])
print split(a, a<5)
```

this will return a list of two arrays containing [1,2,3,4] and [5,6,7,8].

Try using this function based on the conditions you set (intervals of 0.2 it seems)

NOTE: to implement this correctly for your problem, you'll have to modify the split function seeing that you want to split the data into more than two sections. I'll leave that as an exercise for you to do :)

Answer (score 0):

This function takes in two 1D arrays and returns a 2D matrix, in which each element is the number of points in the grid section corresponding to your image:

```
import numpy as np

def count_points(arr1, arr2, bin_width):
    x = np.floor(arr1/bin_width).astype(int) # Bin number for each value
    y = np.floor(arr2/bin_width).astype(int) # Bin number for each value
    counts = np.zeros(shape=(max(x)+1, max(y)+1), dtype=int)
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        row = max(y) - y[i]
        col = x[i]
        counts[row, col] += 1
    return counts
```

Note that x and y don't line up with the column and row index, since the origin is at the bottom left in the plot but the "origin" (index `[0,0`]`) of the matrix is the top left. I rearranged the matrix so that the elements line up with what you see in the photo.

Example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.random.random(100)
y = np.random.random(100)
print count_points(x, y, 0.2) # 0.2 matches the default gridlines in matplotlib

# Output:
#[[8 4 5 4 0]
# [2 5 5 7 4]
# [7 1 3 8 3]
# [4 2 5 3 4]
# [4 4 3 1 4]]
```

Which matches the counts here:

[image]